# Need to display Connection info in variables

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have connection string

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

where con contains connection string info coming from DLL or app.config.

Now i want to display each and every thing in different variables.

e.g:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=172.16.0.9;Initial Catalog=whiziblesem;UserID=mppuser;Password=mppuser";
```

Expected Output:

```
        a = server name
        b = Database name
        c = username
        d = password
```

Comment: Accept answers for some of your past questions, please.

Comment: click the check below the vote number of answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **SqlConnectionStringBuilder** class:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("Data Source: {0}", builder.DataSource);
Console.WriteLine("Initial Catalog: {0}", builder.InitialCatalog);
Console.WriteLine("User ID: {0}", builder.UserID);
Console.WriteLine("Password: {0}", builder.Password);
///...
```

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?